How to speed up generating and filtering large lists of numbers?
I have the following code where I brute force search for two variables.
list gives a list of 3 dimensional vectors, say {x,y,z}. I need to find the vector with the minimum y for which x<epspe. In my code filtered and minElement picks out the optimal vector from the list.
I dont believe the way I wrote filtered and minElement is the most optimal.
How could I improve the code further?
gammaFuncekert = 
  Compile[{{merr, _Real, 0}, {m, _Real, 0}}, 
   1/(merr + 1) + 1/(m - merr + 1), 
   RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}];

ekert = Compile[{{nu, _Real, 0}, {eta, _Real, 0}, {ntrials, _Real, 
     0}, {nsucc, _Real, 0}, {ntot, _Real, 0}}, 
   Exp[-2 ntot ntrials eta^2/(ntot - ntrials + 1)] + 
    Exp[If[-2 gammaFuncekert[ntot (nsucc/ntrials + eta), 
         ntot] ((ntot - ntrials)^2 (nu - eta)^2 - 1) < -700, 
      0, -2 gammaFuncekert[ntot (nsucc/ntrials + eta), 
        ntot] ((ntot - ntrials)^2 (nu - eta)^2 - 1)]], 
   RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}];

ntot = 10^4;
ntrials = 0.1 ntot;
nsucc = 0.0455 ntrials;
epspe = 10^-15;


list = Module[{optvalues, etalist, nulist, serf, prob, tab}, 
    optvalues = {1., 1.};
    serf = 
     Sqrt[ntot (ntrials + 1.) Log[
         1./epspe]/(2. ntrials^2. (ntot - ntrials))];
    ParallelTable[{ekert[i, j, ntrials, nsucc, ntot], i, j}, {j, 
      Range[serf/4, i, (i - serf/4)/(1000 - 1)]}, {i, 
      Range[serf/2, 
       2 serf, (2 serf - serf/2)/(1000 - 1)]}]]; // AbsoluteTiming


filtered = 
   Select[Flatten[list, 1], #[[1]] < epspe &]; // AbsoluteTiming

minElement = MinimalBy[filtered, #[[2]] &]; // AbsoluteTiming

First[minElement][[2 ;; 3]]

(*
Out[47]= {0.95447, Null}

Out[48]= {0.51905, Null}

Out[49]= {0.07404, Null}

Out[50]= {0.142961, 0.124746}
*)



Without a definition of gammaFuncekert we cannot run your code.
One possibility that immediately suggests itself is to reduce the number of calls of Table (you can loop over multiple parameters with one invocation).

Sorry about that Ive edited the code.



optvals = 
  Compile[{{ntot, _Real, 0}, {ntrials, _Real, 0}, {nsucc, _Real, 
     0}, {epspe, _Real, 0}, {nutrials, _Real, 0}, {etatrials, _Real, 
     0}}, Module[{optvalues, etalist, nulist, serf, prob, tab, nuval, 
     etaval, epsval, eps}, optvalues = {1., 1.};
    serf = 
     Sqrt[ntot (ntrials + 1.) Log[
         1./epspe]/(2. ntrials^2. (ntot - ntrials))];
    nuval = 1.;
    etaval = 1.;
    epsval = 
     Min[Flatten[
       Table[Table[
         If[eps = ekert[i, j, ntrials, nsucc, ntot]; eps <= epspe, 
          If[i < nuval, nuval = i; etaval = j; epsval = eps, i], 
          1], {j, Range[serf/4, 
           i, (i - serf/4)/(etatrials - 1)]}], {i, 
         Range[serf/2, 2 serf, (2 serf - serf/2)/(nutrials - 1)]}], 
       1]]; {nuval, etaval, epsval}],
   RuntimeOptions -> {
     "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}];

optvals[ntot, ntrials, nsucc, epspe, 1000, 1000] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.050929, {0.142961, 0.124746, 9.9267*10^-16}}*)

I ditched the ParallelTable and put everything inside Compile. Just iterate over all values of x and saving y and z which satisfies the conditions. The final result is thirty times faster.
